# IndexError with PIL Image and Numpy Array (Alpha Channel Blending)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am encountering an error while trying to run this program. It takes a 'marked' image and blends the RGB values of the markings with the RGB values of the original image. It uses PIL and Numpy to blend the RGB values of two almost-identical images using the images' alpha channel values. The error I encounter is:

```
File "wip.py", line 87, in mark
apixel[channel] = ((apixel[channel]*(apixel[3]/255))+(oapixel[channel]*(oapixel[3]/255)))/2
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

And the relevant code is:

```
img = np.array(marked)
orig_img = np.array(original_image)
for x in range(wmark_w):
    for y in range(wmark_h):
        if img[x][y][3] < 255:
            apixel = img[x][y]
            oapixel = orig_img[x+int(0.02*width)][y+int(0.02*width)]
            for channel in range(4):
                apixel[channel] = ((apixel[channel]*(apixel[3]/255))+(oapixel[channel]*(oapixel[3]/255)))/2
marked = PIL.Image.fromarray(img)
del img; del orig_img
```

'oapixel' is offset because the markings are in a specific rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the original image is not in RGBA format. Convert it with:

```
orig_img = np.array(original_image.convert('RGBA'))
```

See also [image modes.](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/handbook/concepts.html#modes)

Comment: That solved my original error, but now I get a similar one: `File "wip.py", line 85, in mark
    if img[x][y][3] < 255:
IndexError: index 640 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 640` 640 will change to different numbers depending on the resolution of the watermark that I use.

Comment: @L.Teder - That error means that the `x` index goes outside of the image dimensions. How do you get `wmark_w` and `wmark_h`?

Comment: @L.Teder - Ah I think I see the problem: Indexing a numpy array is reversed compared to indexing a PIL image. So everywhere you index an *array* the first index should be `y` and the second should be `x`. Also btw, for style and performance reasons you should index a numpy array with a tuple, instead of consecutive brackets. So `img[x][y][channel]` is written as `img[y,x,channel]`.

Comment: Now I'm getting a (yet again) similar error: `File "wip.py", line 85, in mark if img[x][y][3] < 255: IndexError: index 498 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 498` 498 changes to the resolution of the watermark, but not in the same way as the previous Line 85 IndexError. Thanks for all of your help, by the way.